# copying file from a pod to local machine directly from inside the pod

Tags: kubernetes-pod

Is it possible to copy a file from kubernetes pod to local directly from inside the pod? Actually I am trying to take a db dump and copy it directly to my local. But unable to do it in a single command. command is as below:

*kubectl --kubeconfig kubeconfig.yaml exec -n  mysql_pod -- mysqldump -uroot -p --databases  > new_bkp.sql && kubectl cp /mysql_pod:new_bkp.sql /home/atul/Desktop/new_bkp.sql*

It is working fine for me. But is there anyway so that I can directly copy it to my local machine without using second command with the help of &&?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
$ kubectl --kubeconfig kubeconfig.yaml exec pod_name  -n namespace -- mysqldump -u root -ppassword databasename > location/file_name.sql
```

Comment: Absolutely fine. Its working. Thanks a lot